# Moving magento to a new server breaks its functionality

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, magento, magento-1.6

I've moved a magento install from the current shared hosting to a new VPS.
I also moved it on a staging server.

It works very well on the staging server but it doesn't on the VPS.

The issue I get (when trying to add a product) is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined
```

I moved the DB and the full source base, on both systems... so I can't really figure out why it's not working on the production VPS.

By *googling* it seems that often it was a conflict between jQuery and Prototype but I'm using *noConflict* (and then it's working on the staging server...)

**What can be wrong here?**

I've also tried reconfiguring folder permissions and Web Inspector is not finding any 404.

Answer (score 0):

Pop firebug open, turn browser cache off and then look in the .net panel for any js that is not being loaded. This may have a reference to an old url and you'll need to fix that in the system->config->web admin settings.

Comment: Tried again now, but nothing... everything gets loaded rightly (200 OK). I've also cleaned up the cache, but it's still the same. Any other idea?

Comment: I found the page to not be complete... it interrupts on a div on the production website... it's like missing some template :-/

Comment: try using rsync to get the files synchronized, if you do --exclude app/etc/local.xml it should preserve your db settings.

Comment: but that's pretty weird... I've zipped the same folder... I did it again, and again on the production server the shown HTML is not complete.... what can it be caused by?

Comment: i've also tried reuploading the whole source directory, but nothing, s I opened another question more specific to the issue. Now I'm trying with rsync as you suggested. If you have any suggestion please let me know.